# Stop calling of prompt box once 'Cancel' is clicked

Tags: javascript, timer, prompt

I have timer function which shows the user a `prompt` box when the remaining time goes below a specific value.

**Code Snippet of the call**

```
function countdown(duration, display, show) {
        display.innerHTML = toHHMMSS(duration, show);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){countdown(duration, display, show);}, 1000);
        if(duration<1) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            endSession();
        }
        duration--;
    }

    function toHHMMSS(duration, show) {
        if(duration<300 && show == 1) {
            var newMinutes = prompt("This session will expire in 5 minutes. If you want to extend, enter the minutes below");
            if(newMinutes == null) {
                /* Stop showing the alert box but without affecting the timer */
            }
            var elem = document.getElementById("timer");
            elem.style.color = "Red";
        } else {
            var elem = document.getElementById("timer");
            elem.style.color = "#3BB9FF";
        }
        var sec_num = parseInt(duration, 10); 
        var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        return time;
    }
```

Now, this allows the user to enter a value that  ultimately adds to their timer for the session to run longer.
But the issue comes when the user clicks on *Cancel*. As this check resides in a `setTimeout` call with a interval of 1 sec (the *Timer*), the alert is getting called every second.

**What do I do to stop this from happening and at the same time not break out of this function as that would stop the timer as well**

**EDIT**
Added complete code

Comment: What about a global variable?

Comment: You cannot have two `else`s. Please fix your code, or is that what your question is about?

Comment: What alert, what timeout are you talking about? Please post your complete code.

Comment: @Bergi - First of all, there aren't two else's, it's a nested if. Secondly, I've updated my question and added more code that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would definitely help to post your complete code, but here's a quick JSFiddle showing how I'd go about it: http://jsfiddle.net/eklingen/5zqecaap/1/

Basically I'd go with some globals to hold everything for me:

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var tickInterval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
var alertThreshold = 5;
var remainingTime = 6;
var prompted = false;

function tick() {  
    // Do everything I need to here
}
```

I would however trade out alerts and prompts for modal dialogs to keep that timer running seeing how JS likes to freeze up intervals and timeouts when one of those boxes is being displayed.

Comment: I've added my complete function

Comment: thanks. The `prompted = false` is exactly what I needed